# Understanding Linear Algebra theory

Tags: linear-algebra

Hi I'm currently studying Linear algebra and I just want to get a few bits straight in my head about it:

- if I had a set that had say six vectors is it possible that my span was say $\ R^7 $ ? or can the span only equal the number of vectors?
- Is it possible for All subsets of $\ R^n $ containing n vectors, are linearly independent?
- If I had a vector space - V and S = {u1, u2} is a subset of V . How can I prove that S is linearly independent?

Answer (score 1):

> - if I had a set that had say six vectors is it possible that my span was say $\ R^7 $ ? or can the span only equal the number of vectors?

No. The dimension of $\mathbb{R}^7$ is 7 which means you need at least 7 vectors to span this space. If you have 7 vectors which are also linearly independent, then they span $\mathbb{R}^7$ (they form a *basis*). More than 7 vectors *can* span $\mathbb{R}^7$, but they wouldn't form a basis.

> - Is it possible for All subsets of $\ R^n $ containing n vectors, are linearly independent?

No: take for example $(1,0)$ and $(2,0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, these are linearly dependent. However, if you take *more* than $n$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then you are *sure* they are not all linearly independent. Taking less, gives no guarantees.

Most of the conclusions you can make in this context are 'one way', so you have to be very careful. In $\mathbb{R}^n$, a set of:

- **more** than $n$ vectors will always be linearly dependent (but less than $n$ not necessarily independent);
- **less** than $n$ vectors will never span the space (but more than $n$ won't necessarily span the space).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this has helped a lot but I have come across another area that I want to understand if you could possibly help? If I had a vector space - V 

and S = {u1, u2} is a subset of V . 

How can I prove that S is linearly independent?

Comment: If it's closely related to your previous question(s), perhaps you can just edit this one and add your addition question. If not, it's probably better to make a new question rather than discussing via comments (I think, I'm not that familiar with the site's policy on this).